# Puppeteer JS generate PDF from selector

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdf-generation, puppeteer, html2pdf

I'm familiarizing myself with [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) to use in a Vue.js app but I can't figure out how to generate a PDF based on specific element on the page. I can successfully create a PDF based on the full page, but that's not ideal. Is there a method or class I missed that can allow this? I couldn't find a chainable `page` function to filter by selector(s) like so:

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://what.a.fancy/website', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    await page.$('.just-this-html').pdf(options);
```

I did see there's a `page.$(selector)` function but I'm not sure how to chain that with a `.then()` call that could access the returned HTML to a PDF.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try code this.  `await page.setContent()` [page.setContent](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetcontenthtml)

**Example**

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://www.google.com/', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
const dom = await page.$eval('div.jsb', (element) => {
     return element.innerHTML
}) // Get DOM HTML
await page.setContent(dom)   // HTML markup to assign to the page for generate pdf
await page.pdf(options)
```

Comment: Thanks @aofdev! Is there a way to preserve the CSS that's been applied to the page? it seems like it's lost when the `setContent` call is made.

Comment: I just discovered the `page.addStyleTag` function and that seems to work. Now I just need to figure out how to dynamically loop over the `link[rel=stylesheet]` tags on the page...

Comment: Thanks @aofdev This really helps me, solution works.

Comment: this works, but the only problem is that it wont save the css styling of the content in pdf..

Answer (score 0):

Late to the puppeteer party. However, better late than never. Someone reaching here should test whether this snippet could be useful. Code derived from above answers:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch() //defaults to true 
   const page = await browser.newPage()

 // Create PDF from your URL => replace my fictitious url with your own url for this to work! 
 await page.goto('https://932db2cf7b.ngrok.io/chapter/lesson.php', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'})

const items = await page.$eval('#doto', (element) => {
return element.innerHTML 
}) // Get DOM HTML elements

  await page.setContent(items) 

 await page.pdf({ path: 'pdf/aip.pdf', format: 'A4' })

 await browser.close()
 })()
```

This is getting elements in a div to pdf => aip in a folder named pdf.

I hope the included comments will be helpful

Happy googling!